# Afnetworking multipart/formdata returning request failed in ios 11 but working fine in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, ios11

I'am trying to submit the multipart form data which contains images with some nested JSON's, but its working fine in ios 10 but for ios 11 returning the **Request failed:unacceptable content-type:text/html** error.
code that i have used as shown below, let me know if i'am missing something.

//AFNetworking Multipart

```
func AFhttpPost(url:String,postData:NSMutableDictionary, completionHandler:(result: NSMutableDictionary,error:NSString) -> Void){

    print("postData \(postData)")

    var dataReceived:NSDictionary?
    var mutableData:NSMutableDictionary?
    if(self.checkNetConnectivity())
    {
        let afHTTP :AFJSONRequestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()


        afHTTP.setValue("multipart/form-data;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        afHTTP.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")



        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = afHTTP.multipartFormRequestWithMethod("POST", URLString: url, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWithBlock: {(formData: AFMultipartFormData) in

            let allKeys:NSArray = postData.allKeys


            for item in allKeys.enumerate(){
                let currentKey = item.element as! String

                if(currentKey == "signature"){
                    let signatureImage = postData.objectForKey("signature") as! UIImage

                    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(signatureImage)!
                    formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData , name: "uploaded_file[]", fileName: "signature\(index)x.png", mimeType: "image/png")


                }
                else
                {   //if it is jsonobject and its NSData just send as it is otherwise encode it
                    let postDataBytes:NSData?
                    if(postData.valueForKey(currentKey)! .isKindOfClass(NSData)){
                        postDataBytes = postData.valueForKey(currentKey)! as? NSData

                        print("postDataBytes: \(currentKey):\(postDataBytes)")

                    }else{
                        postDataBytes = postData.valueForKey(currentKey)!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion:true)!

                        print("postDataBytes: \(currentKey):\(postDataBytes)")

                    }
                    formData.appendPartWithFormData(postDataBytes!, name: currentKey)

                }

            }

            print("formFinalData \(formData)")


            }, error: nil)

        let accessToken  = SingleTon().getAccessToken()
        let authorisationheader  = "\(accessToken)"
        request.setValue(authorisationheader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        config.URLCache = nil
        config.URLCredentialStorage = nil
        // let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)




        let managerS : AFURLSessionManager = AFURLSessionManager.init(sessionConfiguration:config)

        managerS.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()




        let uploadTask = managerS.uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest(request, progress: nil) { (response, responseObject, error) -> Void in

            do
            {  print("data \(responseObject)")
                if(responseObject != nil){
                    //dataReceived = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseObject! as! NSData, options: []) as? NSMutableDictionary
                    dataReceived = responseObject! as? NSDictionary

                    mutableData = dataReceived!.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableDictionary
                    completionHandler(result:mutableData! ,error:"")

                }else{
                    completionHandler(result:[:],error:error!.localizedDescription)


                }

            }
        }
        uploadTask.resume()
    }else{

        completionHandler(result: [:],error:ReapConectivityStatus)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your server is sending "text/html" instead of the already supported types. My solution was to add "text/html" to acceptableContentTypes set in AFURLResponseSerialization class. Just search for "acceptableContentTypes" and add @"text/html" to the set manually.